# HTTPS encryption and GET parameters

Tags: encryption, https, server

I have a web service that exposes data via HTTPS.
for example: https://www.sito.it/api/users?acces_token=sfkjsdbhfskjdb

suppose I have to query this web service from an app (android or any other platform).
if someone intercepts traffic between the server and the app, can they see the acess_token?
or not because everything is encrypted by HTTPS ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a secure connection is established between client and server, all the info about the connection (headers, parameters) is encrypted, so only emisor and receptor can see it.

What you have to take care with is not to have any intermediate proxy in a secure connection between client and server.

[Click here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server) for a much more extense and detailed explanation.